# How to execute function after ng-show?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show

I have table in HTML code and buttons with `ng-show=some_property`
The thing which I want to do is :

Button1 which reveals the table in which is field1 on which I want to change focus directly from button1.

But the problem is I can't set button1 as focused because it is invisible.
I try to use `$watch` to detect the change of `some_property` but it is detecting it yet before making table visible.

So in fact my question is how to make something like trigger after `ng-show` not during or just before it.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeout()` or `$timeout()` if you want Angular to kick in digest cycle.
The idea behind it is that JS is a single-threaded, so you have to let current call to end and only after that your code could see the results.

`$scope.$watch('myShow', function() {
  if(whatever)
    $timeout(function(){
       yourCodeHere();
    });
});`